# How can I rotate label with \tkzLabelSegment in tkz-euclide?

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to label the segments AF and DF like this picture.
[image]
I tried.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
\usetkzobj{all} 
\tikzset{hidden/.style = {thick, dashed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,
6/0/B,
6/6/C,
0/6/D}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B)                      \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,D)                      \tkzGetPoint{F}
\tkzLabelPoints[left](F,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,E,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above,right](C)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black](A,B,C,D,E,F)
\tkzDrawSegments[hidden](E,F E,C F,C)
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,D D,A)
\tkzLabelSegment[below=3pt](A,E){3 cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[below=3pt](B,E){3 cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[left=3pt](A,F){3 cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[left=3pt](D,F){3 cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got
[image]

How can I rotate label AF and DF?

Comment: You could try `fill=black` in `\tkzDrawPoints`. I think it produces nicer points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the last two lines in your MWE into:

```
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped](A,F){3 cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped](D,F){3 cm}
```

Please, keep in mind that the order of the points becomes important. The code above will put 3cm at the left of AF, but another 3cm will be at the right of DF. Playing with points you will get what you need.